# Implementation of multi-variable, multi-type RNN in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, categorization

I have a dataset which has items with the following layout/schema:

```
{
    words: "Hi! How are you? My name is Helennastica",
    ratio: 0.32,
    importantNum: 382,
    wordArray: ["dog", "cat", "friend"],
    isItCorrect: false,
    type: 2
}
```

where I have a lot of different types of data, including:

- Arrays (of one type only, e.g an array of strings or array of numbers, never both)
- Booleans
- Numbers with fixed min/max (i.e on a scale of 0 to 1)
- Limitless integers (any integer -∞ to ∞)
- Strings, with some dictionary, some new, words

The task is to create an RNN (**well, generally, a system that can quickly retrain when given one extra bit of data** instead of reprocessing it all - I *think* an RNN is the best choice; see below for reasoning) which can use all of these factors to categorise any dataset into one of 4 categories - labelled by the `type` key in the above example, a number 0-3.

I have a set of lots of the examples in the above format (with answer provided), and I have a database filled with uncategorised examples. My intention is to be able to run the ML model on that set, and sort all of them into categories. The reason I need to be able to retrain quickly is because of the feedback feature: if the AI gets something wrong, any user can report it, in which case that specific JSON will be added to the dataset. Obviously, having to retrain with 1000+ JSONs just to add one extra on would take ages - if I am not mistaken, an RNN can get around this.

I have found many possible use-cases for something like this, yet I have spent literal hours browsing through Github trying to find an implementation, or some Tensorflow module/addon to make this easier/copy, but to no avail.

I assume this would not be too difficult using Tensorflow, and I understand a bit of the maths and logic behind it (but not formally educated, so I probably have gaps!), but unfortunately I have essentially no experience with using Tensorflow/any other ML frameworks (beyond copy-pasting code for some other projects). If someone could point me in the right direction in the form of a Github repo/Python framework, or even write some demo code to help solve this problem, it would be greatly appreciated. And if you're just going to correct some of my technical knowledge/tell me where I've gone horrendously wrong, I'd appreciate that feedback to (just leave it as a comment).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like an interesting use case. If possible, can you please share the data so that we can try resolving it. Thanks!